npm is not working!! Why this error occur when i type "npm -v" or any other of npm
type = npm -v
then
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '../../package.json'
Require stack:

C:\Users\App\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli\validate-engines.js
C:\Users\App\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
C:\Users\App\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js

I install nodejs many times but it never setup then I move to environment setting but again failed

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

hardly I Solve this error so what i do is
1st = remove all temp file
2nd = remove/delete npm remaining file which is present in roaming folder of Appdata there I found lot npm and npm-cache file then I deleted all files after that i deleted the nodejs from control panel and installed new version of nodejs then i successfully run npm!!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
